# Binding SimpleObjectProperty

Tags: java, generics, javafx, classcastexception

I want to bind a simple object property. But I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate.
```

Please this is the code below.

EmployeeShowController.java

```
public class EmployeeShowController implements Initializable{
    @FXML private Label db;

    public void update()throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("EmployeeUpdate.fxml"));
    Parent newParent =loader.load();
    EmployeeUpdateController subController=loader.getController();
    subController.textToDisplay.set(db.getText());

    Stage stage =new Stage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(newParent);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    @Override
    public void initialize(){
    }
}
```

EmployeeUpdateController.java

```
public class EmployeeUpdateController implements Initializable{
    @FXML private DatePicker dateOfBirth;
     public SimpleObjectProperty textToDisplay= new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    @Override
    Public void initialize(){
        dateOfBirth.valueProperty().bind(textToDisplay);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the raw type in the declaration of `textToDisplay` you get rid of the compile time check that would prevent you from assigning a `String` value to it here:

```
subController.textToDisplay.set(db.getText());
```

```
dateOfBirth.valueProperty().bind(textToDisplay);
```

Makes sure the value from the `textToDisplay` is assigned to the value of the `valueProperty()` of your `DatePicker`. `DatePicker` however expects the value to be of type `LocalDate` and somewhere in the internals of `DatePicker` the value from the property is retrieved and effectively cast to `LocalDate` which causes a `ClassCastException` since the actual value is a `String`.

You need to convert the `String` to `LocalDate` to make this work, e.g.

```
public SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> textToDisplay = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

```
subController.textToDisplay.set(LocalDate.parse(db.getText()));
```

Note that depending on the format of the date stored in the `db` label you need to change the code doing the conversion...

For date formats different to [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE), use a appropriate [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) e.g.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

```
subController.textToDisplay.set(LocalDate.parse(db.getText(), DATE_FORMATTER));
```

Comment: how do I assign the value from TextToDisplay to the Value of the valueProperty()  of my DatePicker? I can't figure that out.

Comment: @Helen Added code for converting the `String` to `LocalDate`. Seems a bit illogical to store a date in the fxml file though...

Comment: The code didn't work. I get the error:
    java.time.DateTimeParseException: Text '07/05/2016' could not be   parsed at index 0

Comment: @Helen : Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the date, see updated answer.